# CSS media queries not working 100% any suggestions?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I was dropped into a website build mid construction at this new job of mine. Long story short, I am not much of a front-end developer and that's really all that needs to be done at this point. It was designed for desktop first then media queries going down to smaller sizes. All set with the style of:

```
@media (max-width:1200px)
@media (max-width:990px)
```

etc...

So not being a front end designer I'm new to the whole responsive design. I've managed to get everything to respond and fit the way I want using these media tags however, for example, all styling in the span 1199px - 991px use the styles I set but at the actual 1200px or 990px the media query breaks and I'm left with a funky layout just for that one pixel range. Is there a more appropriate way to layout out my media queries like with a min and max width to fix this? Or better yet, is there a really simple fix for my current set up even if it is not the most pragmatic approach? Just trying to wrap this site up. Thanks community!

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can be a great pain if not written properly.

If you want to auto adjust the layout according to different devices(or different screen sizes) then try using Bootstrap.

It provides simple class, all you gotta do is add the class name to your div.

For example, to fit a div with across the screen you add col-lg-12 (lg for large). Similarly, there's md, sm and xs (medium, small and extra small resp.)

For reference check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: Oh how I wish my friend. I am working in drupal 8 and bootstrap is on the server but little actual evidence of use, It is too late to switch over because I don't want to write out the twig templates or clean up the mess that's already there. I'm talking containers inside of containers inside of rows that add up to like col-md-20. It's a mess the deadline is this week, I have to go full manual responsiveness. Appreciate the response though, I usually use bootstrap with a LESS compiler

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your media query isn't written well, try to write them with an "and" .i.e.

```
@media screen and  (max-width: 989px) { }
```

The styles written in the parenthesis of this query will be used when the screen is less than 989px in width.

You can change the max-width to min-width to show styles in a query that is used when the screen is more than a certain size.

This query will be used when the screen size is between 1200px to 990px.

```
@media screen and  (min-width: 990px) and (max-width: 1200px) { }
```

You can continue adding styles like this, if you want, for example, to add the last query that shows styles for a large screen, you can make it query a min width.

```
@media screen and  (min-width: 1201px) { }
```

If its still bringing problems you can add this meta tag inside the head element before the title tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Got most of the code here at stackoverflow. Hope this helps.